# How to get the plans of a product using stripe-java or rest api

Tags: java, rest, stripe-payments

This question is about [Stripe](https://stripe.com) java (or REST) api, currently version **2019-05-16**.

We have created one product manually through stripe dashboard and have attached three plans to it, one for monthly, quarterly and yearly payments respectively.

Now if I try to get this product through the REST api (same result using `stripe-java`) by doing:

```
 curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/products/prod_...... \
  -u sk_test_........:
```

I get indeed the product object [described in the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/retrieve), which has no `plans` attribute on it.

However, if I inspect the requests made by the `stripe` dashboard itself while visiting the products' page, I can see that in this case the products are indeed retrieved with their respective `plans` attached to it (see "plans" in image below right bottom corner). So I guess the dashboard is using another api, perhaps a more convenient one.

My question is, how can I get all the plans of a product given its product `id`? I guess I can get instead all the plans and then filter by product `id` effectively getting what I want, however this looks to me more like a hack. What are the best practices here?

Why the dashboard api would be different in any case? Thanks all of you in advance.

[image: GET /v1/products?limit=0&include%5B%5D=total_count]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can list all the plans filtered by the product:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/list#list_plans-product

Adding the product id as parameter:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/plans?product=prod_id ...
```

> **product**
> *optional*
>
> Only return plans for the given product.

Comment: yes, but what I want is the opposite: given a product id obtain all the plans attached to it.

Comment: But it's the same, you have the product id and you get all the plans from that product id. This is specified in the Stripe API.